# C#: ExecuteNonQuery() Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Actually i have a page to update profile information.  i Have a code like this

**Controller**

```
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string UpdateClinicName = null;
            string UpdateDrname = null;
            string UpdateClinicFullAddress = null;
            string UpdateClinicFaxNo = null;
            string UpdateClinicPhone = null;
            string UpdateMOHRegistration = null;
            string UpdateClinicEmail = null;
            string UpdateContactID = null;
            string UpdateHospitalRegistrationNo = null;

                // Getting GroupID
            string GroupIDdrinin = null;
            GroupIDdrinin = Profiledatainfo.GroupID;

                // Getting ContactID
            UpdateContactID = Profiledatainfo.CContactID;

               // Getting ClinicName 
            UpdateClinicName = Profiledatainfo.Clinicname;

               // Getting Dr name 
            UpdateDrname = Profiledatainfo.Doctorname;

              // Getting ClinicFullAddress
            UpdateClinicFullAddress = Profiledatainfo.ClinicFullAddress;

              // Getting ClinicPhone 
            UpdateClinicPhone = Profiledatainfo.ClinicPhone;

              // Getting MOHRegistrationNo
            UpdateMOHRegistration = Profiledatainfo.MOHRegistrationNo;


              // Getting FaxNo
            UpdateClinicFaxNo = Profiledatainfo.ClinicFaxNo;

              // Getting Clinic Mail 
            UpdateClinicEmail = Profiledatainfo.ClinicBusinessEmail;

              // Getting HospitalRegistrationNo

            UpdateHospitalRegistrationNo = Profiledatainfo.RegistrationNo;

            ClinicProfileTimingModelDAL UpdateProfileInfo = new ClinicProfileTimingModelDAL();

              // Updating ProfileInformation 
            int Upstatus = UpdateProfileInfo.UpdateClinicProfile(UpdateContactID, UpdateClinicPhone, UpdateClinicFaxNo, UpdateClinicFullAddress, UpdateClinicEmail);
            int Uregistatus = UpdateProfileInfo.UpdateClinicRegistration(GroupIDdrinin, UpdateMOHRegistration, UpdateHospitalRegistrationNo);

        }
```

**Model**

```
  public class ClinicProfileTimingModelDAL
{

    public int UpdateClinicProfile(string ContactID, string ClinicPhone, string ClinicFaxNo, string ClinicAddress, string ClinicBusiessMail)
    {

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("DataBase Conn details");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Execute SpClinicDetAmendMVC " + ContactID + ",'" + ClinicPhone + "','" + ClinicFaxNo + "','" + ClinicAddress + "','" + ClinicBusiessMail + "'";
        //sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select ConfirmVisitID,MemberID,GroupID,RecStatus,CreateUserID,VisitDate from tblConfirmVisit where Cast(VisitDate as Date)='" + Vstdate + "' and CreateUserID="+createuserid+"";


        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
        int Msg = 0;
        Msg = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        return Msg;

    }

    public int UpdateClinicRegistration(string GroupID, string HospitalResitrationno, string MOHRegistrationNo)
    {

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("DataBase Conn details");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Execute spupdateProfileInfoMVC '" + GroupID + "'," + HospitalResitrationno + "," + MOHRegistrationNo + "";
        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
        int Msg = 0;
        Msg = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        return Msg;

    }

}
```

So, when i tried to update the profile information, i have an exception "I am getting an .ExecuteNonQuery() Error. SqlException was unhandled by user code // Incorrect syntax near ','.

**So i tried the alternate way** in Model section

```
     sqlCmd.CommandText = "Execute spupdateProfileInfoMVC(@Cid, @Cp, @Cfn, @Ca, @Cbm) "
    sqlCmd.CommandText.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", ContactID );
    sqlCmd.CommandText.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cp", ClinicPhone  );
    sqlCmd.CommandText.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cfn", ClinicFaxNo);
    sqlCmd.CommandText.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ca", ClinicAddress  );
    sqlCmd.CommandText.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cbm", ClinicBusinessMail);
    sqlCmd.CommandText.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This alternative way also give same exception. So how to solve this issue. Any help appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query string probably has invalid part, all string values must passed in apostrophe before comma like this: `EXEC spupdateProfileInfoMVC '" + GroupID + "','" + HospitalResitrationno + "','" + MOHRegistrationNo + "'"`

Comment: Instead of using `Execute`, you can just make the `CommandText` just the name of the SP, and then set the `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and make sure the parameter names match up with the SP parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TetsuyaYamamoto. Your comment helps me to solve the issue. Now i don't have any exception. But still i cant bale to update. Still i get the old data after submiting update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
qlCmd.CommandText = "Execute spupdateProfileInfoMVC '" + GroupID +
 "','" + HospitalResitrationno + "','" + MOHRegistrationNo + "'";
```

Same with:

```
 sqlCmd.CommandText = "Execute SpClinicDetAmendMVC '" + ContactID + "','" + ClinicPhone + "','" + ClinicFaxNo + "','" + ClinicAddress + "','" + ClinicBusiessMail + "'";
```

Comment: Make sure your SP parameter must all string according to your sample code.